# Define crispy forms context names for two forms in one

Tags: django, forms

I'm trying to create a crispy form with django that has a persistent form at the top, but then a variable form at the bottom of the same page, which is dependent on the choice out of a drop-down menu.

The crispy forms documentation says that this is possible when doing the following:

```
<form action="{% url submit_survey %}" class="uniForm" method="post">
    {% crispy first_form %}
    {% crispy second_form %}
</form>
```

But this is obviously dependent on the context names of the forms, but I can't find any resources that explain how to actually set the context variables of the forms that I want to display.

Below is an example of the top form and a possible bottom form:

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit

class BusinessForm(forms.ModelForm):

    group_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(GroupModel.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BusinessForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'group_id',
            'contact_name',
            'business_name',
            'address_line_1',
            'address_line_2',
            'postcode',
            'telephone',
            'email',
            'web',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('submit', 'Add business', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessModel
        fields = (
            'group_id',
            'contact_name',
            'business_name',
            'address_line_1',
            'address_line_2',
            'postcode',
            'telephone',
            'email',
            'web',
        )

class AttractionExtrasForm(forms.ModelForm):

    classification_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(AttractionClassModel.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwagrs):
        super(AttractionExtrasForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'classification_id',
        )

    class Meta:
        model = AttractionExtrasModel
        fields = (
            'classification_id',
        )
```

And the view:

```
class BusinessView(
    views.LoginRequiredMixin,
    views.FormValidMessageMixin,
    generic.edit.CreateView
):

    form_class = BusinessForm
    model = BusinessModel
    template_name = "businesses/business.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('businesses:add_business')
    from_valid_message = "You have successfully created a business."

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(BusinessView, self).form_valid(form)
```

And the template:

```
{% extends '_layouts/base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
Add business | {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}

{% block headline %}
<h1>Add business</h1>
{% endblock headline %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url add_business %}" method="post">
    {% crispy form %}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

That will display the normal form since it's only calling the form variable.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view**:

```
 class BusinessView(...):
 ...

 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super(BusinessView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['form_2'] = AttractionExtrasForm(instance=self.model())  # if createview
      # context['form_2'] = AttractionExtrasForm(instance=self.object)  # if updateview     

      return context
```

And you have to validate both separately

```
if form.is_valid() and form_2.is_valid():
    return self.form_valid(form, form_2)
else:
    return self.form_invalid(form, form_2)
```

If you models is connected (one have FK field to another)

```
def form_valid(self, form, form_2):
    if not self.object:  # createview
        self.object = form.save()
    else:  # updateview
        form.save()

    form_2.instance = self.object
    form_2.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def form_invalid(self, form, form_2):
    return self.render_to_response(
        self.get_context_data(
            form=form,
            form_2=form_2
        )
    )
```

And if you want many instances of `form_2` can use inlineformset_factory https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet

**template**:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    {% crispy form_2 %}
</form>
```

Comment: That did the trick. I had researched up get_context_data but clearly didn't research it enough. Cheers!