# Crispy Forms: FormHelper for split forms / two columns same model

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

My Template is divided into two columns.
I have only one Model but aiming for split a form into two, one part in the first column, another part in the second column. I aim for using FormHelper for Crispy Forms.

Available Documentation gives a cryptic hint but without any examples such attempt to an explanation falls a bit short.

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/tags.html#rendering-several-forms-with-helpers

> **Rendering several forms with helpers**
>
> Often we get asked: “How do you render two or more forms, with their
>   respective helpers, using {% crispy %} tag, without having  tags
>   rendered twice?” **Easy**, you need to set form_tag helper property to
>   False in every helper:
>
> ```
> self.helper.form_tag = False
> ```
>
> Then you will have to write a little of html code surrounding the
>   forms:
>
> ```
> <form action="{% url submit_survey %}" class="uniForm" method="post">
>     {% crispy first_form %}
>     {% crispy second_form %}
> </form>
> ```

**UPDATE:** This post explains the passus of the Crispy documentation
[Define crispy forms context names for two forms in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589395/define-crispy-forms-context-names-for-two-forms-in-one)

Below is my code. The two FormHelper divide the Model into two parts, first part with fields: `['car_model_make', 'status_is_secondhand']` 
second part with fields: `['seller', 'buyer']`

What I have been looking for is a way to "call" upon a specific `{% crispy form %}`. Given the "help" documentation" such would look as `{% crispy product-modelform_1 %}` and `{% crispy product-modelform_2 %}` which does not work.

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Models):
    car_model_make = models.CharField(default='B', max_length=1, blank=True, choices=CAR_TYPE)
    status_is_secondhand = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, choices=SELLER_TYPE)
    buyer = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, choices=BUYER_TYPE)

# forms.py
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
        self.helper.form_id = 'product-modelform'
        self.helper.form_tag = False


        model = 'car_model_make'
        secondhand = 'status_is_secondhand'

        self.fields[model].label = "Model"
        self.fields[secondhand].label = "Is Secondhand"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(model),
            Field(secondhand),
            )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
        self.helper.form_id = 'product-modelform'
        self.helper.form_tag = False


        seller = 'seller'
        buyer = 'buyer'

        self.fields[seller].label = "Seller"
        self.fields[buyer].label = "buyer"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(seller),
            Field(buyer),
            )

# views.py
class ProductFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('product/', ProductFormView.as_view(template_name='product/product.html'),


# html template

{% extends "product/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block col8_content %}
<form id="product-modelform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    {% endblock col8_content %}
    {% block col4_content %}   
</form>
    {% endblock col4_content %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for now (mainly inspired from [Define crispy forms context names for two forms in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589395/define-crispy-forms-context-names-for-two-forms-in-one) but here I have created two new forms based upon a ModelForm): I wish I fully understood the solution better myself, but at least it works as intended.

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Models):
    car_model_make = models.CharField(default='B', max_length=1, blank=True, choices=CAR_TYPE)
    status_is_secondhand = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, choices=SELLER_TYPE)
    buyer = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, choices=BUYER_TYPE)

# forms.py
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('__all__')

class CarForm(ProductForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

        model = 'car_model_make'
        secondhand = 'status_is_secondhand'

        self.fields[model].label = "Model"
        self.fields[secondhand].label = "Is Secondhand"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(model),
            Field(secondhand),
            )

class TransactionForm(ProductForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
        self.helper.form_tag = False


        seller = 'seller'
        buyer = 'buyer'

        self.fields[seller].label = "Seller"
        self.fields[buyer].label = "buyer"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field(Seller),
            Field(buyer),
            )

# views.py
class ProductFormView(FormView):
    form_class = CarForm
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form_2'] = TransactionForm(instance=self.model())
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form,
            )
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('product/', ProductFormView.as_view(template_name='product/product.html'),


# html template

{% extends "product/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block col8_content %}
<form id="product-modelform" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
    {% endblock col8_content %}
    {% block col4_content %}
    {% crispy form_2 %}
</form>
    {% endblock col4_content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two `__init__` methods and you don't need it actually. You may just enclose those two 'columns' inside two separate `<div>` tags with the help of FormHelper().

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      self.helper = FormHelper()
      self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
      self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-4'
      self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-8'
      self.helper.form_id = 'product-modelform'
      self.helper.form_tag = False
      self.helper.layout = Layout(
      Div(
        Div('car_model_make','status_is_secondhand', css_class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'),
        Div('seller','buyer', css_class='col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'),
        css_class='row'
        )
      )
```

Hope, this gives you the trick. Refer [Layouts](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/d-0/layouts.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks, given your answer, I have updated my question. Meanwhile it would work as you suggest, but in my case the actual layout is unfortunately much more complex and I would need a "block" to insert. But, if this is the only solution, I would need to place all that formatting into the div.

Comment: May I know the purpose of those block and endblock inside form?

Comment: Block above was referring to "insert a form object, such as {% crispy form %}" (sry for confusing terms). The idea of using Blocks in my template was as I removed the Tags 'self.helper.form_tag = False' and had a manual form in my second column, this was the way I manage to save both Forms. So, Block col8 is my left column, and Block col4 is my right column. In each block there is a form, both forms come from the same Model and I would need to save them both at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Can you update the post with the contents of your block tags?

Comment: sry for missunderstanding, added the the content, essentially a list of foldable cards, each contains form fields (from the same model)